# Why I need to scroll up and down first before the collection view cell updated?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

[image]

I am trying to make a category list using `CollectionView`, as we can see there is a brown circle that actually an `UIView` (Designable Background View).

I want to update that background colour from brown to random colour. but the random colour only show up after I scroll up and scroll down the `CollectionView`, like the .gif file in here : http://g.recordit.co/BxRf26Uw2t.gif

before scroll down the colour will be still in brown like this
[image]

after scroll up and down, the colour will be updated, but some of the item still in the brown colour like this :

[image]

here is the code of my `ViewController`

```
import UIKit
import ChameleonFramework


class FacilitiesVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionVIew: UICollectionView!

    struct StoryBoard {
        // Collection View
        static let indoorFacilitiesCategoryCellIdentifier = "indoorFacilitiesCell"
        static let numberOfColumnsPerRow : CGFloat = 3.0
        static let inset: CGFloat = 10.0
        static let spacing: CGFloat = 8.0
        static let lineSpacing: CGFloat = 8.0

        //segue Identifiers
    }


    var indoorFacilitiesCategoryData = [FacilitiesCategory]()
    var outdoorFacilitiesCategoryData = [FacilitiesCategory]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        getIndoorOutdoorFacilitiesData()

    }



}


extension FacilitiesVC {

    func getIndoorOutdoorFacilitiesData() {

        let facilitiesData = FacilitiesCategoryLibrary.fetchFacilitiesCategory()

        // distinguishing between indoor and outdoor data
        for facData in facilitiesData {

            if facData.type == "Indoor Facility" {
                indoorFacilitiesCategoryData.append(facData)
            } else {
                outdoorFacilitiesCategoryData.append(facData)
            }
        }
    }

}



extension FacilitiesVC : UICollectionViewDataSource {
    // MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return indoorFacilitiesCategoryData.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: StoryBoard.indoorFacilitiesCategoryCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! IndoorFacilitiesCell
        cell.indoorFacilitiesCategoryData = indoorFacilitiesCategoryData[indexPath.item]
        cell.designableBackgroundView.backgroundColor = RandomFlatColor()
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 1

        return cell
    }


}
```

and here is the code of `CollectionViewCell`

```
import UIKit
import ChameleonFramework

class IndoorFacilitiesCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var designableBackgroundView: DesignableUIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var iconImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var icontitleLabel: UILabel!

    var indoorFacilitiesCategoryData : FacilitiesCategory? {
        didSet {
            updateUI()
        }
    }

}

extension IndoorFacilitiesCell {

    func updateUI() {
        guard let indoorData = indoorFacilitiesCategoryData else {return}

        iconImageView.image = UIImage(named: indoorData.logo)
        icontitleLabel.text = indoorData.categoryName
    }

}
```

what went wrong in here? what should I do to fix that?

Comment: just use `- (void)reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths` method when you want to change color.

Comment: Can you show `DesignableUIView` class?

Comment: This is  line causing the problem `cell.designableBackgroundView.backgroundColor = RandomFlatColor()` 
bucuse scroll up or down  reusable cells 
look apple documentation documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview read  Creating Cells and Supplementary Views

Comment: @trungduc no it doesn't have custom class, just in interface builder

Comment: @sarah Try to check `RandomFlatColor()` before set it for `cell.designableBackgroundView.backgroundColor`. Maybe have problem with this funtion

Comment: @sarah I have searched and Swift doesn't have any class called `DesignableUIView`

Comment: @trungduc thank you very much :) , but the problem is still the same if I change RandomFlatColor() to UIColor.blue, yes it is just UIView that I rename to it to DesignableUIView, to facilitate the background color

Comment: @a.masri yes I suspect thats line is the problem, but I really don't know what to do

Comment: @sarah You mean that if you change to `UIColor.blue`, the color only is updated after you scroll. Is it right?

Comment: @trungduc yup, exactly like that :)

Comment: @sarah please share DesignableUIView code also.

Comment: @sarah try add new param in `FacilitiesCategory` class ex : `mainColor`
on append in `indoorFacilitiesCategoryData` set `mainColor = RandomFlatColor() ` then in `updateUI()` add this code `designableBackgroundView.backgroundColor = indoorData.mainColor`